# How can I use CASE-WHEN to set a null valued column show as 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

One of my fields are null and I am trying to use distinct to filter out the redundant and records which are repeated. This is my SQL statement which calculates checks value based on being drawn and not!

```
SELECT   CASE SUM(Money)
             WHEN null THEN sum(0)
             ELSE SUM(Money)
         END AS MoneyTaken
FROM     (SELECT   Money
          FROM     tblPayment AS tblPayment_1
          WHERE    (CheckStatus = 0) AND (IDBuyer = @BuyerID) AND (IDSource = @SourceID)
          GROUP BY ID, IDBuyer, IDSeller, Money) AS derivedtbl_1_1) AS [Cheques Which didnt have credit], tblPurchase.Price AS SellPrice
```

but this doesn't work and I still get `NULL` in `MoneyTaken` Column when executing the function.

This is my full stored procedure which still shows repeated results :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SGetListofKharIDBuyer]
@SurceId bigint,
@BuyerId bigint
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    /*
    0 = check(cheque)  dosent have credit-so couldntget money out of it
    1 = check(cheque) has credit- got the money
   -1 = in cashe  - paid in cash
    */

SELECT     distinct   vPatmentForReport.Account, vPatmentForReport.PaymentStatus, vPatmentForReport.Description, vPatmentForReport.Bank, vPatmentForReport.Serial, 
                         vPatmentForReport.PaymentMethod, vPatmentForReport.Date, vPatmentForReport.مبلغ * Money AS [Payment in Cash], tblPurchase.Date AS [PurchaseDate], 
                         tblReserve.Fee , tblReserve.NumberOfReserve , tblReserve.TotalMoney ,
                             (SELECT         COALESCE( SUM(Money),0) AS [PaidMoney]
                                FROM            (SELECT        Money
                                                           FROM            tblPardakht
                                                           WHERE        (CheckStatus <> 0) AND (IDBuyer = @BuyerId) AND (IDSource = @SurceId)
                                                           GROUP BY ID, IDBuyer, IDAccount, Money) AS derivedtbl_1) AS [Sum of Cheques and in cash payments],
                             (SELECT       COALESCE( SUM(Money),0) AS [PaidMoney]
                                FROM            (SELECT        Money
                                                           FROM            tblPardakht AS tblPardakht_1
                                                           WHERE        (CheckStatus = 0) AND (IDBuyer = @BuyerId) AND (IDSource = @SurceId)
                                                           GROUP BY ID, IDBuyer, IDAccount, Money) AS derivedtbl_1_1) AS [sum of cheques which are not drawn], tblPurchase.Money , 
                         tblReserve.Description , tblReserve.Date
FROM            tblPurchase INNER JOIN
                         tblReserve ON tblPurchase.IDReserve = tblReserve.ID inner JOIN
                         vPatmentForReport ON tblReserve.IDSource = vPatmentForReport.[SourceId] AND tblReserve.IDBuyer = vPatmentForReport.[BuyerId]
WHERE        (vPatmentForReport.[BuyerId] = @BuyerId) AND (vPatmentForReport.[SourceId] = @SurceId)
```

`vPatmentForReport` is a view which is made by a function without any parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Money),0), ....
```

Comment: @abatishchev perform the same.

Comment: Thank you very much.This is done and i get 0 great job :), but my distinct doesn't work again.what could be other cause ?

Comment: @Hossein i can't find distinct in your query. can you show it?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
SELECT   SUM(Money) as  MoneyTaken
FROM     (SELECT   Money
          FROM     tblPayment AS tblPayment_1
          WHERE    (CheckStatus = 0) AND (IDBuyer = @BuyerID) AND (IDSource = @SourceID) and ISNULL(Money,0)<> 0
          GROUP BY ID, IDBuyer, IDSeller, Money) AS derivedtbl_1_1) AS [Cheques Which didnt have credit], tblPurchase.Price AS SellPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as you will get NULL in case your subselects won't return any row, use ISNULL outside of the subselects:  e.g.

```
,ISNULL(
(SELECT SUM(Money) AS [PaidMoney]
FROM (SELECT  Money
FROM tblPardakht 
WHERE (CheckStatus <> 0) AND (IDBuyer = @BuyerId) AND (IDSource = @SurceId)
GROUP BY ID, IDBuyer, IDAccount, Money) AS derivedtbl_1) 
,0) AS [Sum of Cheques and in cash payments]
```